# Save last datePicker selection

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uidatepicker

I have a project with an `UIDatePicker`.

I want that if I change my `UIDatePicker` value, for example at 9:23, when I restart my app value is still 9:23 and not the default value. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
var datePicker = /* Get Your Date Picker from somewhere */

// Store value using User Defaults
let currentDate = datePicker.date
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentDate, forKey: "Current-Date")

// Retrieve Value using User Defaults
if let date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Current- Date") as? NSDate {
   datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
}
```

I tried with standard `userDefaults` method but not worked.

Comment: let currentDate = myDatePicker.date

Comment: myDatePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)

Comment: You have a problem also with your key "Current-Date" !=  "Current- Date"

Comment: delete var datePicker = /* Get Your Date Picker from somewhere */

Comment: i'm trying to adjust that

Comment: BTW you should load/set your date picker date inside viewDidAppear

Comment: i get this error: value of type NSUserdefaults has no member setDate

Comment: you need to add my extension from that link I posted

Comment: Ok i put that instead in viewDidLoad

Comment: I made this: put in viewDidAppear that code:let currentDate = myDatePicker?.date
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentDate, forKey: "Current-Date")
        
        
        if let date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Current-Date") as? NSDate {
            myDatePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
        }

Comment: myDatePicker?.date change to myDatePicker.date

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ae8mswwz5x2p60w/localNotification.zip?dl=0

Comment: Works very well...many thanks!!!

Comment: i just only changed    myDatePicker?.setDate(loadedDate, animated: false) because without ? i get sometimes exception found nil while unwrapping optional value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29837976/2303865

Comment: I think if you place it inside viewDidAppear you should use animated, if you don't want to see an animation place it inside viewWillAppear

Comment: Leo i need your help for another question...are you ready?

Comment: Here is the link to new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288785/swift-cancel-a-local-notification-and-scheduling-a-new-one

Answer (score 4):

Hi I prepared for you some snipped code:

```
     import UIKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController {

// I have declared const key property to avoid mistakes (typo)
            let dateKey = "Current-Date"

            @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
            }

            override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
                super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // This line load previous state when view controller did appear
                loadDate(true)
            }

            @IBAction func savePickerData(sender: AnyObject) {
                // When user taps into 'savePickerData' button picker state is saved
                saveDate()
            }

            func saveDate() {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(datePicker.date, forKey:dateKey)
            }

            func loadDate(animation: Bool) {
                guard let loadedDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(dateKey) as? NSDate else { return }

                datePicker.setDate(loadedDate, animated: animation)
            }

        }
```

Should works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Your key is not the same **"Current-Date" != "Current- Date"**. That is why it is not working :

```
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentDate, forKey: "Current-Date")
...
    if let date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Current- Date") as? NSDate {
```

Use a constant to avoid this error:

```
let keyData = "Current-Date"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentDate, forKey: keyData)
...
    if let date = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(keyData) as? NSDate {
```